# Looping code to export raster from stack

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am trying to code a loop that creates and exports rasters from a stack. The stack is composed of data for 20 individual animals that I processed from my original dataframe (e.g. `animal$ID`)  Here is the code I have written so far.

```
uni<-unique(animal$ID)

for (i in 1:length(uni)){
    subtest<- animalstack [i]  
    ras<-raster(subtest[[1]])
    values(ras)<- values(subtest[[1]])
    outrasname<- paste("DIRECTORY", paste('animal_ID',   
    as.character(uni[l]),sep="_"),sep="/") 
    writeRaster(ras, outrasname, format="HFA")
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :   unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’.

Comment: Where does that `raster()` function come from? Is it a package or did you write it? Would be nice to look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do use the `bylayer` argument and do it in one line:

```
writeRaster(animalstack, "animal_ID", bylayer=TRUE, format="HFA")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
uni<-unique(animal$ID)

for (i in 1:length(uni)){
    ras <- subtest[[i]]
    outrasname<- paste("DIRECTORY", paste('animal_ID',   
    as.character(uni[i]),sep="_"),sep="/") 
    writeRaster(ras, outrasname, format="HFA")
}
```

When you are subsetting a stack the `[]` operator gives you the values for that cell number for every layer. That is why you were getting the error. The `[[]]` operator returns the specified layer from the stack.